# How to add a subview (like a label) to a UIViewController's main view which already has subviews?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios9

I'm working with a framework that creates UIViewControllers with its specific controls. I don't have access to its storyboard to manually modify it. Is there a way to add something like a label to its view and position it properly even if the view already has its autolayout configured?

The existing UIViewController has a view with a label, a textfield, and a button on the bottom of the screen. I want to add another label underneath the textfield. How do I go about doing something like that?

I tried using:

```
view.insertSubview(label, belowSubview: textField)
```

but the label ends up in the upper-left corner and it's not part of the view's autolayout (i.e. when I change screen size, the existing controls do the right thing, only my label gets lost).

Comment: Did you correctly set the x:y coordinates of the view that you are adding? Note that insert above is with respect to the z order, not the x:y position.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the label is not properly position because there isn't any constraint on it.

Can you try the following code?

```
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    self.view.insertSubview(label, belowSubview: textField)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint])
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you to add a new view to view hierarchy and tie its position to one of the existing views using AutoLayout. You have to of course have access to that existing view.

We can assume that the original view hierarchy is not under/over constrained, so you should not worry too much about your view messing things up.

You basically need to constrain

1. its **size** which is very easy as the constraint is applied only on that view and then
2. the view's **position** which will be relative to any view you select from the existing view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The `below` in `insertSubview(belowSubview:)` refers to z-positioning, not y-positioning as your assuming.  Since you're not giving any positioning to the label, it defaults to 0,0.  It sounds like you're using auto layout, so you need to give appropriate constraints:

```
view.addSubview(label)
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```